# selecting style attribute of an element with simple function parameter?

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I'm basically trying to update the value of an element's specified style attributes (without messing up or overwriting the other style properties) with a simple function. For example, this function would allow you to input "top" as a parameter and access/edit the value of element.style.top (or conversely, element.style.left if you input "left").

For some context, my particular function would allow users to resize an element by shifting the position of its edges (and thus changes the top, bottom, left or right positioning attributes) so the value assigned responds dynamically to the user's inputs (and thus can't be pre-determined by a CSS class).

Some possibilities I thought of:

```js
function changeStyleAttribute(el,attr) { //doesn't work (wrong syntax?) 
el.style.attr = new_value
} 

function changeStyleAttribute(el,attr) { //doesn't work (wrong syntax?)
el.setAttribute("style.attr",new_value)
} 

function changeStyleAttribute(el,attr) { //could work but seems hack-y?
el.setAttribute(attr,new_value) //overwrites all style attributes with property of interest
el.classList.add(old_classes) //re-introduces all other default attributes of the element

}
```

I feel like maybe there's a much more straightforward elegant way to do this in native javascript that I'm missing?

Comment: Try `el.style[attr] = new_value`

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed! Yay, learning basic syntax :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If key of the property is dynamic value or variable, use [**`Square bracket notation`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Note: You are not setting the attribute but adding/modifying css rule.

```js
function changeStyleAttribute(el, cssRule) {
  el.style[cssRule] = value;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment, but accessing the attribute the way you and Quantumplate suggested does seem to directly update the element's style property (and not just the css rule)

Comment: (Unless you were referring to my own suggestion of adding classes to my element, which I can now see problems with in hindsight)